# React router is loading same component for routes defined below that particuler route

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have created routes in `app.js` and `/`, `/create-receipt` and `/login` routes are working fine but if I go to `/signup` route or any other route below `/login` it loads the `Login` component, if I remove `login` and `signup` component then the routes are working perfectly.

App.js:-

```
<Router>
  <Header/>
  <Switch>
    <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
    <Route path="/create-receipt" component={CreateReceipt} />
    <Route Path="/login" component={Login} />
    <Route Path="/signup" component={Signup} />
    <Route path="/fast-food-receipt" exact component={FastFoodReceipt} />
    <Route path="/fast-food-receipt/receipt-one" component={FastFoodReceiptOne} />
    <Route path="/fast-food-receipt/receipt-two" component={FastFoodReceiptTwo} />
    <Route path="/fast-food-receipt/receipt-three" component={FastFoodReceiptThree} />
    <Route path="/fast-food-receipt/receipt-four" component={ReceiptFour} />
    <Route path="/fast-food-receipt/receipt-five" component={FastFoodReceiptFive} />
    <Route path="" component={NotFound} />
  </Switch>
  <Footer/>
</Router>
```

Login.js:-

const Login = () =>{
return(
login page
)
}

export default Login;

Signup.js:-

const Signup = () =>{
return(
signup page
)
}

export default Signup;

NOTE:-  issue is coming when i use route component like this

```
<Route Path="/signup"  component={Signup} /> 
<Route Path="/login"  component={Login} />
```

working fine when i am using route component in this way:-

```
<Route exact path="/"><Home /></Route>
<Route  path="/login"><Login /></Route>
<Route  path="/signup"><Signup /></Route>
```

can some one tell why it is happening

Comment: What is the content of `FastFoodReceipt`? Maybe it's redirecting the user to `/login`.

Comment: issue is coming when i use route component like this <Route Path="/login"  component={Login} />  but it is working fine in <Route  path="/login"><Login /></Route> this way i don't understand why

Comment: Not sure what is causing the problem, but using `Route` with children is the recommended way.